# $ identifier works in cpp how is this possible?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
int $;
$=1000;
cout<<$;
return 0;}
```

when I run this code it runs successfully but according to language it should give error on using $ as identifier so can anyone help me in better  understanding this?But according to many books and tutorials $ cannot be used as identifier and the editor is showing error for @ and % but not for $ why so? please explain

Comment: Why are you tagging c? If it is not related please remove it.